# How to extract a bitmap from a video?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am working on a Java Application on Android Studio. **I wanted any code where we can get Bitmap from video**. I take video using absolute path. The input from video is 8 FPS.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(absolutePath);
```

Just wanted to take Bitmap from video. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean thumbnail? If yes then use -  ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(absolutePath,
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code and it worked

```
 MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
   try {
        //path of the video of which you want frames
        retriever.setDataSource(absolutePath);
    }catch (Exception e) {

    }

    String duration = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    int duration_millisec = Integer.parseInt(duration); //duration in millisec
    int duration_second = duration_millisec / 1000;  //millisec to sec.
    int frames_per_second = 30;  //no. of frames want to retrieve per second
    int numeroFrameCaptured = frames_per_second * duration_second;
    long frame_us=1000000/30;
    capture=="+numeroFrameCaptured);

    for (int i = 0; i < numeroFrameCaptured; i++)
    {
        //setting time position at which you want to retrieve frames

        MEventsManager.getInstance().inject(MEventsManager.IMAGE,retriever.getFrameAtTime(frame_us*i,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST));
    }

    retriever.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want image from video then you can use library called FFMPEG by implementing in gradle with this:

```
 implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-min:4.3.1.LTS'
```

By using several commands you can convert all frames of video into image or you can get single frame also

for more information please visit:-

```
 https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg
```

if you want only frame for displaying in imageview then you can use glide/picasso library.

Hope this will Help you..!!!